# In plain English, what is recursion?

Tags: recursion

The idea of recursion is not very common in real world. So, it seems a bit confusing to the novice programmers. Though, I guess, they become used to the concept gradually. So, what can be a nice explanation for them to grasp the idea easily?

Comment: More information is being shared on this subject at [Resources for improving your comprehension of recursion?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/57243/15466)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion

Comment: Recursion is when a function can call itself.  "If you totally understand namespaces and scope and how parameters are passed to a function, then you know recursion already.  I can show examples, but you should be able to figure out how they work on your own."  Students generally struggle with recursion not so much because it's confusing, but because they don't have a firm grasp of variable scope/namespace.  Before diving into recursion, make sure the students can properly trace through a program where you've purposely given variables at different scopes the same name to confuse them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down

Comment: There is a famous book that tackles the difficult problem of recursion *in the real world*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel,_Escher,_Bach

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion

Comment: To Understand Recursion, You Must First Understand Recursion

Comment: Mirror in a mirror.  Dream in a dream. Story in a story.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To explain [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), I use a combination of different explanation, usually to both try to:

- explain the concept,
- explain why it matters,
- explain how to get it.

For starters, [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=recursion) defines it in more simple terms than [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion):

> An expression such that each term is generated by repeating a particular mathematical operation.

---

### Maths

If your student (or the person you explain too, from now on I'll say student) has at least some mathematical background, they've obviously already encountered recursion by studying series and their notion of [recursivity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recursivity) and their [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

A very good way to start is then to demonstrate with a series and tell that it's quite simply what recursion is about:

- a mathematical function...
- ... that calls itself to compute a value corresponding to an n-th element...
- ... and which defines some boundaries.

Usually, you either get a "huh huh, whatev'" at best because they still do not use it, or more likely just a very deep snore.

---

### Coding Examples

For the rest, it's actually a detailed version of what I presented in the **Addendum** of [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/whats-a-nice-explanation-for-pointers/17958#17958) for the [question you pointed to regarding pointers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/whats-a-nice-explanation-for-pointers) (bad pun).

At this stage, my students usually know how to print something to the screen. Assuming we are using C, they know how to print a single char using `write` or `printf`. They also know about control loops.

I usually resort to a few repetitive and simple programming problems until they get it:

- the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) operation,
- an alphabet printer,
- a reversed alphabet printer,
- the [exponentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) operation.

**Factorial**

Factorial is a very simple math concept to understand, and the implementation is very close to its mathematical representation. However, they might not get it at first.

[image: Recursive Definition of the Factorial Operation]

**Alphabets**

The alphabet version is interesting to teach them to think about the ordering of their recursive statements. Like with pointers, they will just throw lines randomly at you. The point is to bring them to the realization that a loop can be inverted by either modifying the conditions **OR** by just inverting the order of the statements in your function. That's where printing the alphabet helps, as it's something visual for them. Simply have them write a function that will print one character for each call, and calls itself recursively to write the next (or previous) one.

<sup>*FP fans, skip the fact that printing stuff to the output stream is a side effect for now... Let's not get too annoying on the FP-front. (But if you use a language with list support, feel free to concatenate to a list at each iteration and just print the final result. But usually I start them with C, which is unfortunately not the best for this sort of problems and concepts).*</sup>

**Exponentiation**

The exponentiation problem is slightly more difficult (*at this stage* of learning). Obviously the concept is exactly the same as for a factorial and there is no added complexity... except that you have multiple parameters. And that is usually enough to confuse people and throw them off at the beginning.

Its simple form:

[image: Simple Form of the Exponentiation Operation]

can be expressed like this by recurrence:

[image: Recurrence Relation for the Exponentiation Operation]

**Harder**

Once these simple problems have been shown AND re-implemented in tutorials, you can give slightly more difficult (but very classic) exercises:

- The [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) numbers,
- The [Greatest Common Divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor),
- The [8-Queens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) problem,
- The [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) game,
- And if you have a graphical environment (or can provide code stubs for it or for a terminal output or they can manage that already), things like:

  - [Koch's Snow Flake Fractal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake),
  - [Sierpinski's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).
- And for for practical examples, consider writing:

  - a tree traversal algorithm,
  - a simple mathematical expression parser,
  - a minesweeper game.

*Note: Again, some of these really aren't any harder... They just approach the problem from exactly the same angle, or a slightly different one. But practice makes perfect.*

---

### Helpers

**A Reference**

Some reading never hurts. Well it will at first, and they'll feel even more lost. It's the sort of thing that grows on you and that sits in the back of your head until one day your realize that you finally get it. And then you think back of these stuff you read. The [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion),  [recursion in Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) pages on Wikipedia would do for now.

**Level/Depth**

Assuming your students do not have much coding experience, provide code stubs. After the first attempts, give them a printing function that can display the recursion level. Printing the numerical value of the level helps.

**The Stack-as-Drawers Diagram**

Indenting a printed result (or the level's output) helps as well, as it gives another visual representation of what your program is doing, opening and closing stack contexts like drawers, or folders in a file system explorer.

**Recursive Acronyms**

If your student is already a bit versed into computer culture, they might already use some projects/softwares with names using [recursive acronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym). It's been a tradition going around for some time, especially in GNU projects. Some examples include:

Recursive:

- GNU - "GNU's Not Unix"
- Nagios - "Nagios Ain't Gonna Insist On Sainthood"
- PHP - "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor" (and originall "Personal Home Page")
- Wine - "Wine Is Not an Emulator"
- Zile - "Zile Is Lossy Emacs"

Mutually Recursive:

- HURD - "HIRD of Unix-Replacing Daemons" (where HIRD is "HURD of Interfaces representing Depth")

Have them try to come up with their own.

Similarly, there are many occurrences of recursive humor, like [Google's recursive search](http://www.google.com/search?q=recursion) correction. [For more information on recursion, read this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/a-nice-explanation-for-recursion/25545#25545).

---

### Pitfalls and Further Learning

Some issues that people usually struggle with and for which you need to know answers.

**Why, oh God Why???**

Why would you do that? A good but non-obvious reason is that it is often simpler to express a problem that way. A not-so-good but obvious reason is that it often takes less typing (don't make them feel soooo l33t for just using recursion though...).

Some problems are definitely easier to solve when using a recursive approach. Typically, any problem you can solve using a [Divide and Conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) paradigm will fit a multi-branched recursion algorithm.

**What's N again??**

Why is my `n` or (whatever your variable's name) different every time? Beginners usually have a problem understanding what a variable and a parameter are, and how to things named `n` in your program can have different values. So now if this value is in the control loop or recursion, that's even worse! Be nice and do not use the same variable names everywhere, and make it clear that **parameters are just variables**.

**End Conditions**

How do I determine my end condition? That's easy, just have them say the steps out loud. For instance for the factorial start from 5, then 4, then ... until 0.

**The Devil is in the Details**

Do not talk to early abut things like [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). I know, I know, TCO is nice, but they don't care at first. Give them some time to wrap their heads around the process in a way that works for them. Feel free to shatter their world again later on, but give them a break.

Similarly, don't talk straight from the first lecture about the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and its memory consumption and ... well... the [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). I often tutor students privately who show me lectures where they have 50 slides about *everything* there's to know about recursion when they can barely write a loop correctly at this stage. That's a good example of how a reference will help *later* but right now just *confuses* you deeply.

But please, in due time, make it clear that there are [reasons to go the iterative or recursive route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursion_versus_iteration).

**Mutual Recursion**

We've seen that functions can be recursive, and even that they can have multiple call points (8-queens, Hanoi, Fibonacci or even an exploration algorithm for a minesweeper). But what about [mutually recursive calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)? Start with maths here as well. `f(x) = g(x) + h(x)` where `g(x) = f(x) + l(x)` and `h` and `l` just do stuff.

Starting with just mathematical series makes it easier to write and implement as the contract is clearly defined by the expressions. For instance, the [Hofstadter Female and Male Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Female_and_Male_sequences):

[image: Hofstadter's Male and Female Sequences]

However in terms of code, it is to be noted that the implementation of a mutually recursive solution often leads to code duplication and should rather be streamlined into a single recursive form (See [Peter Norvig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norvig)'s [Solving Every Sudoku Puzzle](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

Comment: I am reading your answer after seeing it after almost 5th or 6th time. It was nice but too long for attracting other users here I think. I learned many things about teaching recursion here. As a teacher, would you please evaluate my idea for teaching recursion- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/a-nice-explanation-for-recursion/25098#25098

Comment: @Gulshan, I think this answer is about as comprehensive as any is going to be and is easily 'skimmed' by a casual reader. Hence, it gets a `static unsigned int vote = 1;` from me. Forgive the static humor, if you will :) This is the best answer so far.

Comment: @Gulsan: only the one who wants to learn is willing to take the time to do is properly :) I don't really mind. Sometimes, a short answer is elegant and conveys a lot of useful and necessary information to get started or explain a general concept. I just wanted a longer answer for that one, and considering the OP mentions a question for which I was awarded the "correct" answer and asks a similar one, I tought it appropriate to deliver the same sort of answer. Glad you learned something.

Comment: @Gulshan: Now regarding your answer: the first point confused me a lot, I have to say. I like that you describe the concept of recursive functions as something that changes state incrementally over time, but I think that your way of presenting is a bit strange. After reading your 3 points, I wouldn't expect many students to suddenly be able to solve Hanoi. But it might just be a wording issue.

Comment: I've come across of good way of showing that the same variable can have different values in differing depths of recursion: consider having students write down the steps they're taking,  and the values of variables, in following some recursive code. When they reach a recursion, have them start again on a new piece. Once they reach an exit condition, have them move back to the previous piece. This is essentially emulating a call stack, but it's a good way to show these differences.

Comment: @AndyBursh: Yes, that's what I call the "stack-as-drawers" diagram. An another approach is to have them take small sheets of paper, and write each state of a new card, and pile them up, thus literally representating the stacked values for the same variable name.

Comment: @DeadMG: :) I understand it may not necessarily be the best approach. This is the standard way things were done in my engineering school. Very intensive C/UNIX for the first 2 years (and it's C89), then eventually picking up other stuff (C++, Java, Perl) during year 2 and 3, and some other stuff and more freedom to use other languages for years 4 and 5 (C#). We have a rather strict approach.

Comment: @DeadMG: Problem with starting with C is that it puts people off. The good thing is that you start with the basics, and that in this school we absolutely don't care about putting people off, as it's meant for very motivated people with a passion for programming. They like it or leave. Wherever and whenever I teach, I try to keep that alive as much as possible, though in classic university programs some students don't really want to be here, so you need to be more lenient for them. I try to adapt my course to pass this spirit to the motivated ones, while keeping it OK for the others.

Comment: @DeadMG: Also, starting with C allows you to then be able to bridge or make relatively educated assumptions (that you should verify whenever possible though) about how higher-level languages work, like [understanding array and string differences in Java vs C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3874035/453590) :) But I agree with you, sometimes it's better to start with fun languages, and I advocate that as well sometimes especially if motivation is lacking, like I was trying to convey in this othe question about [how to keep learning](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/151242/3631).

Comment: I thought the question specified "plain English".

Comment: Pleased to see this question (and thus this answer) made it to the Dec 31, 2019, Software Engineering.SE newsletter. I thought that question looked familiar! :D

Answer (score 60):

The calling of a function from within that same function.

Comment: This is the best explanation to start from really. Simple and to the point; once you've established this summary, then go into all the head-trip details.

Answer (score 27):

### Recursion is a function that calls itself.

How to use it, when to use it and how to avoid bad design are important to know, which requires you to try it out for yourself, and understand what happens.

The most important thing you need to know is to be very careful to not get a loop that never ends. [The answer from pramodc84](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/a-nice-explanation-for-recursion/25058#25058) to your question has this fault: It never ends...
A recursive function must always check for a condition to determine if it should call itself again or not.

The most classic example to use recursion, is to work with a tree with no static limits in depth. This is a task that you must use recursion.

Comment: You can still implement your last paragraph in an iterative manner, though recursively would obviously be better. "How to use it, when to use it and how to avoid bad design are important to know, which requires you to try it out for yourself, and understand what happens."I thought the point of the question was to get an explanation for that sort of things.

Comment: @haylem: You are right about that answer to the "How to use it, when to use it and how to avoid bad design.." would be more on spot to what the OP asks for (not just "try it out for yourself" as I said), but that would require an extensive lecture of the more teaching kind, rather than a quick answer to a question here. You did a very good job with [your answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/whats-a-nice-explanation-for-recursion/25545#25545) though. +1 for that... Those who really need to get a better grasp of the concept will benefit from reading your answer.

Comment: what about a pair of functions that call each other. A calls B which calls A again until some condition is reached. will this still be considered recursion?

Comment: Yes, the function `a` still calls itself, just indirectly (by calling `b`).

Comment: @santiagozky: As **kindall** said, it is still recursion. However, I would recommend not to do it. When using recursion, it should be very clear in the code that recursion is in place. If calling itself indirectly through another function, it makes it much harder to see what's going on. If you don't know that a function effectively calls itself, you can get in the situation where you (or someone else that did not create this function) break some condition for the recursion (while changing functionality in the code), and you end up in a dead-lock with a never-ending loop.

Answer (score 21):

**Recursive programming is the process of progressively reducing a problem in to easier to solve versions of itself.**

Every recursive function tends to:

1. take a list to process, or some other structure, or problem domain
2. deal with the current point/step
3. call itself on the remainder(s)/subdomain(s)
4. combine or use the results of the subdomain work

When step 2 is before 3, and when step 4 is trivial (a concatenation, sum, or nothing) this enables [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion).  Step 2 often must come after step 3, as the results from the subdomain(s) of the problem may be needed in order to complete the current step.

Take the traversal of a straight forward binary tree.  The traversal can be made in pre-order, in-order, or post-order, depending on what is required.

```
   B
A     C
```

**Pre-order: B A C**

```
traverse(tree):
    visit the node
    traverse(left)
    traverse(right)
```

**In-order: A B C**

```
traverse(tree):
    traverse(left)
    visit the node
    traverse(right)
```

**Post-order: A C B**

```
traverse(tree):
    traverse(left)
    traverse(right)
    visit the node
```

Very many recursive problems are specific cases of a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) operation, or a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) - understanding just these two operations can lead to significant understanding of good use-cases for recursion.

Comment: The key component to practical recursion is the idea of using the solution to a slightly smaller problem to solve a larger one. Otherwise, you just have infinite recursion.

Comment: @Barry Brown: Quite right. Hence my statement *"... reducing a problem in to easier to solve versions of itself"*

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say so... It is often the case, especially in divide and conquer problems or for situations where you really define a recurrence relation that comes down to a simple case. But I'd say it's more about proving that for each iteration N of your problem, there's a computable case N + 1.

Comment: @Sean McMillan: Recursion is a powerful tool when used in domains that suit it.  All too often I see it used as a *[clever](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/why-is-cleverness-considered-harmful-in-programming-by-some-people)* way to handle some relatively trivial issue, that massively obfuscates the true nature of the task at hand.

Answer (score 20):

The OP said that recursion doesn't exist in the real world, but I beg to differ.

Let's take the real world 'operation' of cutting up a pizza. You've taken the pizza out of the oven and in order to serve it up you have to cut it in half, then cut those halves in half, then again cut those resultant halves in half.

The operation of cutting the pizza you performing again and again until you've got the result you want (the number of slices). And for arguments sake let's say that an uncut pizza is a slice itself.

Here's an example in Ruby:

```
def cut_pizza(existing_slices, desired_slices)
  if existing_slices != desired_slices
    # we don't have enough slices yet to feed everyone, so
    # we're cutting the pizza slices, thus doubling their number
    new_slices = existing_slices * 2 
    # and this here is the recursive call
    cut_pizza(new_slices, desired_slices)
  else
    # we have the desired number of slices, so we return
    # here instead of continuing to recurse
    return existing_slices
  end
end

pizza = 1 # a whole pizza, 'one slice'
cut_pizza(pizza, 8) # => we'll get 8
```

So the real world operation is cutting a pizza, and the recursion is doing the same thing over and over until you have what you want.

Operations you'll find that crop up that you can implement with recursive functions are:

- Calculating compound interest over a number of months.
- Looking for a file on a file system (because file systems are trees because of directories).
- Anything that involves working with trees in general, I guess.

I recommend writing a program to look for a file based on it's file name, and try to write a function that calls itself until it's found, the signature would look like this:

`find_file_by_name(file_name_we_are_looking_for, path_to_look_in)`

So you could call it like this:

`find_file_by_name('httpd.conf', '/etc') # damn it i can never find apache's conf`

It's simply programming mechanics in my opinion, a way of cleverly removing duplication. You can rewrite this by using variables, but this is a 'nicer' solution. There is nothing mysterious or difficult about it. You'll write a couple of recursive functions, it'll click and *huzzah* another mechanical trick in your programming tool box.

**Extra Credit** The `cut_pizza` example above will give you a stack level too deep error if you ask it for a number of slices that isn't a power of 2 (i.e 2 or 4 or 8 or 16). Can you modify it so that if someone asks for 10 slices it wont run for ever?

Answer (score 16):

Okay i am going to try to keep this simple and concise.

Recursive function are functions that call themselves. Recursive function consist of three things:

1. Logic
2. A call to itself
3. When to terminate.

Best ways to write recursive methods, is to think of the method that you trying to write as a simple example only handling one loop of the process you want to iterate over, then add the call to the method itself, and add when you want to terminate. Best way to learn is to practice like all things.

Since this is programmers website I will refrain from writing code but here is a good [link](http://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=recursion&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=b70f85f807d51e40)

if you got that joke you got what recursion means.

Comment: See also this answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/a-nice-explanation-for-recursion/25057#25057 (-:

Comment: Strictly, recursion doesn't need a termination condition; guaranteeing that recursion terminates limits the types of problems that the recursive function can solve, and there are some types of semantic presentations that do not require termination at all.

Answer (score 6):

Recursion is a tool a programmer can use to invoke a function call on itself. Fibonacci sequence is the textbook example of how recursion is used.

Most recursive code if not all can be expressed as iterative function, but its usually messy. Good examples of other recursive programs are Data Structures such as trees, binary search tree and even quicksort.

Recursion is used to make code less sloppy, keep in mind it is usually slower and requires more memory.

Comment: Whether it is slower or requires more memory very much depends on the use at hand.

Comment: Fibonacci sequence calculation is a terrible thing to do recursively.  Tree traversal is a much more natural use of recursion.  Typically, when recursion is used well, it isn't slower and doesn't require more memory, since you'd have to maintain a stack of your own instead of the call stack.

Comment: @Dave: I wouldn't dispute that, but I think Fibonacci is a good example to start with.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use this one:

### How do you walk to the store?

If you're at the entrance to the store, simply go through it.
Otherwise, take one step, then walk the rest of the way to the store.

It's critical to include three aspects:

- A trivial base case
- Solving a small piece of the problem
- Solving the rest of the problem recursively

We actually use recursion a lot in daily life; we just don't think of it that way.

Comment: THat is not recursion.  It would be if you split it in two:  Walk half the way to the store, walk the other half.  Recurse.

Comment: This is recursion. This isn't divide and conquer, but it is only one type of recursion. Graph algorithms (like path finding) are full of recursive concepts.

Comment: This is recursion, but I consider it a poor example, as it is too easy to mentally translate "take one step, then walk the rest of the way to the store" into an iterative algorithm.  I feel like this is equivalent to converting a nicely written `for` loop into a pointless recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

The best example that I would point you to is C Programming Language by K & R. In that book (and I am quoting from memory), the entry in index page for recursion (alone) lists the actual page where they talk about recursion and the index page as well.

Answer (score 2):

Josh K already mentioned the [Matroshka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRussian-Matroshka.jpg) dolls. Assume that you want to learn something that only the shortest doll knows. The problem is that you can't really talk to her directly, because she originally lives [inside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRussian-Matroshka2.jpg) the taller doll which on the first picture is placed on her left. This structure goes like that (a doll lives inside the taller doll) until ending up only with the tallest one.

So the only thing that you can do is to ask your question to the tallest doll. The tallest doll (who doesn't know the answer) will need to pass your question to the shorter doll (which on the first picture is on her right). Since she also doesn't have the answer she needs to ask the next shorter doll. This will go like that until the message reaches the shortest doll. The shortest doll (who is the only one who knows the secret answer) will pass the answer to the next taller doll (found on her left), which will pass it to the next taller doll... and this will continue until the answer reaches its final destination, which is the tallest doll and finally... you :)

This is what recursion really does. A function/method calls itself until getting the expected answer. That's why when you write recursive code it's very important to decide about when recursion should terminate.

Not the best explanation but it hopefully helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Recursion** *n.* - A pattern of algorithm design where an operation is defined in terms of itself.

The classic example is finding the factorial of a number, n!. 0!=1, and for any other natural number N, the factorial of N is the product of all natural numbers less than or equal to N. So, 6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720. This basic definition would allow you to create a simple iterative solution:

```
int Fact(int degree)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=degree; i>1; i--)
       result *= i;

    return result;
}
```

However, examine the operation again. 6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1. By the same definition, 5! = 5*4*3*2*1, meaning that we can say 6! = 6*(5!). In turn, 5! = 5*(4!) and so on. By doing this, we reduce the problem to an operation performed on the result of all previous operations. This eventually reduces to a point, called a base case, where the result is known by definition. In our case, 0!=1 (we could in most cases also say that 1!=1). In computing, we are often allowed to define algorithms in a very similar way, by having the method call itself and pass a smaller input, thus reducing the problem through many recursions to a base case:

```
int Fact(int degree)
{
    if(degree==0) return 1; //the base case; 0! = 1 by definition
    else return degree * Fact(degree -1); //the recursive case; N! = N*(N-1)!
}
```

This can, in many languages, be further simplified using the ternary operator (sometimes seen as an Iif function in languages that don't provide the operator as such):

```
int Fact(int degree)
{
    //reads equivalently to the above, but is concise and often optimizable
    return degree==0 ? 1: degree * Fact(degree -1);
}
```

Advantages:

- Natural expression - for many types of algorithms, this is a very natural way to express the function.
- Reduced LOC - It's often much more concise to define a function recursively.
- Speed - In certain cases, depending on language and computer architecture, recursion of an algorithm is faster than the equivalent iterative solution, usually because making a function call is a faster operation at the hardware level than the operations and memory access required to loop iteratively.
- Divisibility - Many recursive algorithms are of the "divide and conquer" mentality; the result of the operation is a function of the result of the same operation performed on each of two halves of the input. This allows you to split the work in two at each level, and if available you can give the other half to another "execution unit" to process. This is typically harder or impossible with an iterative algorithm.

Disadvantages:

- Requires understanding - You simply must "grasp" the concept of recursion in order to understand what's going on, and therefore write and maintain effective recursive algorithms. Otherwise it just looks like black magic.
- Context-dependent - Whether recursion is a good idea or not depends on how elegantly the algorithm can be defined in terms of itself. While it is possible to build, for example, a recursive SelectionSort, the iterative algorithm is typically the more understandable.
- Trades RAM access for call stack - Typically, function calls are cheaper than cache access, which can make recursion faster than iteration. But, there's usually a limit to the depth of the call stack that can cause recursion to error where an iterative algorithm will work.
- Infinite recursion - You have to know when to stop. Infinite iteration is also possible but the looping constructs involved are usually easier to understand and thus to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The example I use is a problem I faced in real life. You have a container (such as a large backpack you intend to take on a trip) and you want to know the total weight. You have in the container two or three loose items, and some other containers (say, stuff sacks.) The weight of the total container is obviously the weight of the empty container plus the weight of everything in it. For the loose items, you can just weigh them, and for the stuff sacks you could just weigh them or you could say "well the weight of each stuffsack is the weight of the empty container plus the weight of everything in it". And then you keep going into containers into containers and so on until you get to a point where there are just loose items in a container. That's recursion.

You may think that never happens in real life, but imagine trying to count, or add up the salaries of, people in a particular company or division, which has a mixture of people who just work for the company, people in divisions, then in the divisions there are departments and so on.  Or sales in a country that has regions, some of which have subregions, etc etc.  These sorts of problems happen all the time in business.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can be used to solve a lot of counting problems. For example, say you have a group of n people at a party (n > 1), and everyone shakes everyone else's hand exactly once. How many handshakes take place? You may know that the solution is C(n,2) = n(n-1)/2, but you can solve recursively as follows:

Suppose there are just two people. Then (by inspection) the answer is obviously 1.

Suppose you have three people. Single out one person, and note that he/she shakes hands with two other people. After that you have to count just the handshakes between the other two people. We already did that just now, and it is 1. So the answer is 2 + 1 = 3.

Suppose you have n people. Following the same logic as before, it is (n-1) + (number of handshakes between n-1 people). Expanding, we get (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1.

Expressed as a recursive function,

f(2) = 1
f(n) = n-1 + f(n-1), n > 2

Answer (score 0):

In life (as opposed to in a computer programme) recursion rarely happens under our direct control, because it can be confusing to make happen. Also, perception tends to be about the side effects, rather than being functionally pure, so if recursion is happening you might not notice it.

Recursion does happen out here in the world though. A lot.

A good example is (a simplified version of) the water cycle:

- The sun heats the lake
- The water goes up into sky and forms clouds
- The clouds drift over to a mountain
- At the mountain the air becomes too cold for their moisture to be retained
- Rain falls
- A river forms
- The water in the river runs into the lake

This is a cycle that causes its self to happen again. It is recursive.

Another place you can get recursion is in English (and human language in general). You might not recognise it at first, but the way we can generate a sentence is recursive, because the rules allow us to embed one instance of a symbol in side another instance of the same symbol.

From Steven Pinker's The Language Instinct:

> if either the girl eats ice cream or the girl eats candy then the boy eats hot dogs

That is a whole sentence that contains other whole sentences:

> the girl eats ice cream
>
> the girl eats candy
>
> the boy eats hot dogs

The act of understanding the full sentence involves understanding smaller sentences, which use the same set of mental trickery to be understood as the full sentence.

To understand recursion from a programming perspective it's easiest to look at a problem that can be solved with recursion, and understand why it should be and what that means you need to do.

For the example I will use the greatest common divisor function, or gcd for short.

You have your two numbers `a` and `b`. To find their gcd (assuming neither is 0) you need to check if `a` is evenly divisible into `b`. If it is then `b` is the gcd, otherwise you need to check for the gcd of `b` and the remainder of `a/b`.

You should already be able to see that this is a recursive function, as you have the gcd function calling the gcd function. Just to hammer it home, here it is in c# (again, assuming 0 never gets passed in as a parameter):

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{   
    if (a % b == 0) //this is a stopping condition
    {
        return b;
    }

    return (gcd(b, a % b)); //the call to gcd here makes this function recursive
}
```

In a programme, it is important to have a stopping condition, otherwise you function will recur forever, which will eventually cause a stack overflow!

The reason to use recursion here, rather than a while loop or some other iterative construct, is that as you read the code it tells you what it is doing and what will happen next, so it is easier to figure out if it is working correctly.

Comment: I found the water-cycle example iterative. The second language-example seems more divide-and-conquer than recursion.

Comment: @Gulshan: I would say the water cycle is recursive because it causes its self to repeat, like a recursive function. It's not like painting a room, where you carry out the same set of steps over several objects (walls, ceiling, etc.), like in a for loop. The language example does use divide and conquer, but also the "function" that is called calls its self to work on the nested sentences, so is recursive in that way.

Comment: In water-cycle, the cycle is started by sun and no other element of the cycle is making the sun starting it again. So, where is the recursive call?

Comment: There isn't a recursive call! Isn't not a function. :D It is recursive because it causes its self to recur. The water from the lake comes back to the lake, and the cycle starts again. If some other system was putting water into the lake, then it would be iterative.

Comment: The water cycle is a while loop.  Sure, a while loop can be expressed using recursion, but doing so will blow the stack.  Please don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real world example for recursion.

Let them imagine that they have a comic collection and you're going to mix it all up into a big pile. Careful -- if they really have a collection, they may instantly kill you when you just mention the idea to do so.

Now let them sort this big unsorted pile of comics with the help of this manual:

```
Manual: How to sort a pile of comics

Check the pile if it is already sorted. If it is, then done.

As long as there are comics in the pile, put each one on another pile, 
ordered from left to right in ascending order:

    If your current pile contains different comics, pile them by comic.
    If not and your current pile contains different years, pile them by year.
    If not and your current pile contains different tenth digits, pile them 
    by this digit: Issue 1 to 9, 10 to 19, and so on.
    If not then "pile" them by issue number.

Refer to the "Manual: How to sort a pile of comics" to separately sort each
of the new piles.

Collect the piles back to a big pile from left to right.

Done.
```

The nice thing here is: When they are down to single issues, they have the full "stack frame" with the local piles visible before them on the ground. Give them multiple printouts of the manual and put one aside each pile level with a mark where you currently are on this level (ie. the state of the local variables), so you can continue there on each Done.

That's what recursion basically is about: Performing the very same process, just on a finer detail level the more you go into it.

Answer (score -1):

- Terminate if exit condition reached
- do something to alter the state of things
- do the work all over starting with the present state of things

Recursion is a very concise way to express something that has to be repeated until something is reached.

Answer (score -1):

Not plain english, not really real life examples, but two ways of learning recursion by playing:

- [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)
- [Baguenaudier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baguenaudier)

Answer (score -2):

A nice explanaition of recursion is literally 'an action that reoccurs from within itself".

Consider a painter painting a wall, it's recursive because the action is "paint a strip from ceiling to floor than scoot over a little to the right and (paint a strip from ceiling to floor than scoot over a little to the right and (paint a strip from ceiling to floor than scoot over a little to the right and ( etc )))".

His paint() function calls itself over and over again to make up his bigger paint_wall() function.

Hopefully this poor painter has some kind of stop condition :)

Comment: To me, the example seems more like an iterative procedure, not recursive.

Comment: @Gulshan:  Recursion and iteration do similar things, and often things will work well with either.  Functional languages typically use recursion instead of iteration.  There are better examples of recursion where it would be awkward to write the same thing iteratively.